# Hard coding routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Let's say I have this:

```
<%= link_to "My Big Link", page_path(:id => 4) %>
```

And in my page.rb I want to show urls by their permalink so I use the standard:

```
 def to_param
    "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
 end
```

Now when I click "My Big Link" it takes me to the correct page, but the url in the address bar does not display the desired permalink. Instead it just shows the standard:

```
wwww.mysite.com/pages/4
```

Is this because I hard-coded an id into the page_path? It also does not work if I use straight html like..

```
<a href="/pages/4">My Big Link</a>
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could verify this same behavior and let me know if this intended or not. I need the ability to hard code :id's to specify exact pages...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPDATE TO MY QUESTION ---------------------->

Thanks all for the answers. This was kind of a one off situation. My solution was to simply go with html:

```
<a href="/pages/4-great-title-here">My Big Link</a>
```

Which produced the desired:

```
wwww.mysite.com/pages/4-great-title-here
```

I didn't want to loop through page objects and waste a call to the database for this one link. Much appreciated for all the answers though!

Answer (score 5):

Just use page_path(page). I guess the path helpers don't access the database themself (which is good), but if they are being supplied with an object and that object has a to_param method this method is being used to generate an identifier.

```
<%= link_to "My Big Link", page_path(page) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are specifying the id:

```
page_path(:id => 4)
```

You could specify the path you want in this method:

```
page_path(:id => "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}")
```

Where have you defined the to_param method? In the model?

Comment: Hi Toby, Yes it's in page.rb. I am still unclear as to why specifying the :id would not take that :id and call the to_param method in page.rb?

Comment: Actually I can see why - I guess I am more looking for a workaround :)